# How to define some clickable areas on ImageView (like HTML image map)

Tags: android, imageview, imagemap

Let's say I have an ImageView displaying a school map:
[image]

I want to define some clickable regions on the image (like HTML image map), something like this:

```
Point musicRoom = new Point(30,70);
Point schoolGarden = new Point(120, 80);
Point library = new Point(60, 50);
Point cafetaria = new Point(60, 40);
Point mainOffice = new Point(70, 60);
```

Then I can handle the click events on each point, e.g is `musicRoom` poins is clicked, a Toast will appear. Or if `schoolGarden` point is clicked, another activity will be started.

Is there a library to easily achive this? I tried [ClickcableImagesAreas](https://github.com/LukasLechnerDev/ClickableAreasImages):

```
implementation 'com.github.Lukle:ClickableAreasImages:v0.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
```

Doesn't compile because the library seems to depend on an old, hardcoded PhotoView library
[image]

Comment: You need at least two points to define an area/region.

Comment: Can you determine the coordinates of the point that is clicked?

Comment: @blackapps theoritically: 4 top corners. but I think the problem is hardcoded coordinates will not work properly on different devices, with different screen sizes, yes?

Comment: You can work with percentages.

Comment: But you did not answer if you could determine coordinates of the point that was clicked.

Comment: @anta40, Facing the same issue. Got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use just **imagemap.io** platform to solve this issue. There you can add tooltips for your clickable area.
You can find an example here https://imagemap.io/examples/demo-product